# Identity Server 4+.NET Core 2.0 + Identity

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I have an angular app i want to authorize with Identity Server 4. So, i created database with ef, managed to login with Identity, but i constantly getting **"User is not authenticated"** from Identity Server. I do not use mvc as all examples with Identity Server, so just angular app which i want to authorize. My setup looks like this:

Config.cs:

```
public class Config
{

    private readonly IOptions<IdentityServerOption> _options;

    public Config(IOptions<IdentityServerOption> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("myApi", "Login API")
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "webClient",
                ClientName = "Web Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:4200"
                },

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "myApi"
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    "http://localhost:4200/home/"
                },
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

// database setup works fine, didn't show it
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.AddOptions();

        services.AddIdentityServer(o =>
            {
                o.IssuerUri = "http://localhost:5000";

            })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>().AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            // define policy that allows calling through this app
            options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins(isOptions.AllowedCorsOrigins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.ApiName = "myApi";
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
        services.AddMvc();

    }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseCors("default");

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I am obviously missing something, can anyone help?

UPDATE:

This is what i get in console:

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?client_id=webClient&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4300%2Fhrapps%2F&response_type=id_token%20token&scope=profile%20openid%20hrApi&nonce=N0.31465047010288671529050394126&state=15290500220560.42473005339627434
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
      {
        "ClientId": "webClient",
        "ClientName": "Web Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/home",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:4200/home"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "ResponseType": "id_token token",
        "ResponseMode": "fragment",
        "GrantType": "implicit",
        "RequestedScopes": "profile openid myApi",
        "State": "15290500220560.42473005339627434",
        "Nonce": "N0.31465047010288671529050394126",
        "Raw": {
          "client_id": "webClient",
          "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/home",
          "response_type": "id_token token",
          "scope": "profile openid myApi",
          "nonce": "N0.31465047010288671529050394126",
          "state": "15290500220560.42473005339627434"
        }
      }
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing login: User is not authenticated
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 175.2379ms 302
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DwebClient%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A4200%252Fhome%252F%26response_type%3Did_token%2520token%26scope%3Dprofile%2520openid%2520myApi%26nonce%3DN0.31465047010288671529050394126%26state%3D15290500220560.42473005339627434

Comment: How did you set up authentication in your Angular app? What responses do you get from the Identity Server?

Comment: I have setup the client with angular-oidc lybrary, and client credentials are ok, but when IS tries to authenticate the user it breaks. I need to investigate is IS aware of Users table in db...

Comment: You should have identityserver.log file somewhere (C:\\logs\ folder maybe), take a look what gets written there and post it here.

Comment: @SašaĆetković I updated the question with console output

Comment: FYI: You can remove `app.UseAuthentication();` (this is handled by `app.UseIdentityServer();`).

Comment: Do you really want to both serve *and* consume IdentityServer in this single application?

Comment: This project should scale, plan for future is to split auth service from the domain logic. @KirkLarkin - do you have some proposals for current implementation (regarding authorization)?

Comment: The reason I asked was due to the call to `AddAuthentication("Bearer")`, which sets the default authentication scheme to `Bearer` and might be causing IS4 to be looking in the wrong place for your User.

Comment: I think that the problem is definitely in the place where IS goes for user, but I'm not really sure where the problem is...

Comment: Try it out. Remove that call to `AddAuthentication` and `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` temporarily and see if anything changes.

Comment: I just tried, but i can't register AddIdentityServerAuthentication directly in latest IS version, but services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerAuthentication()... Still not authenticated...

Comment: Has the user's email been confirmed?  Look at the EmailConfirmed column in the Users table.